# MVC 3 Razor Ajax BUGs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

ajax link is:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("AjaxLink","GetText","Home", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "ajaxDiv", HttpMethod = "Get"})

<div id="ajaxDiv"></div>
```

---

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetText()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:
GetText.cshtml:

```
<div>Some text @DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()</div>
```

---

ok, it work. But, if I clik on link over and over again, Page slows down. The more time I clicked on, the longer time on page hangs.
I used the debug:

And it turned out that after the first click, the function GetText () is called once, after the second click, the function is called twice, after the third - three, and so on. In what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning a PartialView instead of a full view so that it returns only the HTML snippet you want without including the master view.  I suspect that the handler is getting re-applied via the master, but there's not really enough information in your question to be sure.

Comment: I also used PartialView (), result in yet the same.

Comment: @SirRoland - use a partial and check the actual content being returned using Firebug (or similar).  The only thing I can think of that would cause the behavior you describe is the handler being reapplied via the result.

Comment: I do not know what I did, but it already works. Already about 30 minutes looking for the reason why it's so retarded, and to no avail. (